# Show image in a div with fixed width/height (100px)

Tags: javascript, css, image

So i have a div that is 100px wide/high, in it i want to show an image (lets say the image is 200px in width/height).
The image should not be resized, the div should only show the center of the image (100px of it) and hide the rest.

You can better see what i mean in the image below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg4hn.png

```
<div class="crop-image">
<a href="some link"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg4hn.png" /></a>
</div>
```

And if the image is smaller than 100px apply a padding to the link of
 
(100px - image width)/2 for padding left and right
(100px - image height)/2 for padding top and bottom

Comment: Use a background image instead.

Comment: I would suggest doing it via background image, that you could center and offset, or you could use negative margins on the image element to set what's visible in the area.

Comment: The image should be a link i'm sorry i forgot to add it first. I have edited the question.

Comment: @CK13 with my solution you may still use a link around the image

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `background-image` and `background-position` like so:

```
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-image:url('http://www.placehold.it/200/200/');
    background-position:center;
}
```

Here is a fiddle showing it off: http://jsfiddle.net/A4wQE/

By setting the height and width of the `div` element you can "crop" an image that is larger. Also, use `background-position:center;` to make sure it is always centered in the `div`.

**UPDATE**

Since you need the image to be a link you can simply wrap the `div` in an `a` tag. As of HTML5, `<a>` elements are allowed to contain block elements.

Comment: The image should be a link i'm sorry i forgot to add it first. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

If your image conveys content it should not be placed as a background: so you could use the `object-fit` property.

By default the image will be in center position, but you can change it via `object-position`

```css
.crop-image {
   height: 100px;
   width : 100px;
}


.crop-image img {
   max-width: 100%;
   object-fit: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="crop-image">
   <a href="#">
     <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" />
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be what i want. Thanks.